# Windows NDES / SCEP URL is using the CA's hostname, can I change this to the FQDN?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, ad-certificate-services

First off I need to describe the environment my team is using for Testing and development.

- A single class C address space.
- 4 AD using the this address space.
- A single Bind9 DNS server acting as a secondary for all of the AD zones.
- No trusts between the AD.
- Our Developtment group requires FQDN on every url.

I just recently configured a new DC and a CA and added SCEP/NDES service. Currently the URL being given out by SCEP/NDES is the hostname.  See image: [NDES request page, no FQDN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs3SO.png)

Is there a way to change the generated URL on this page to include the FQDN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ca01` is in a domain, and DNS registration is properly working then the address `ca01.fulldomain.example.org` should work perfectly fine, and be valid as the hostname component of your URL.

Comment: I tested this right after seeing this,  the FQDN works fine. My Development team is lazy and wants the URL listed on the webpage to be FQDN.

Comment: The current issue is the name given on the SCEP/NDES page is the just the host-name, ie:  CASC, not the FQDN of CASC.Enterprise4.local  So tossing the host-name to the DNS server gives a fault. All of the hosts tied to this network use a generic DHCP host that's not part of an AD Domain along with have a single DNS server acting as secondary to all the domains using this same vlan. 

 I'm going to give the Answer to Zoredache.  I can not figure it out, but I managed to get my Developers and QA to manually type the FQDN in and ignore the address link given on the page. Basically his answer.